# Keep my selected option in a form - laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel-8

in my form i have a select and if i edit i want keep select the option i try with isset but i dont know how to use it in a select

this is my select:

```
    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="id_raza">Raza</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="id_raza" name="id_raza" placeholder="Raza">
        @foreach ($razas as $raza)
            <option value="{{$raza->id}}">{{ $raza->Nombre}}</option>
        @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
```

my controller:

```
    public function edit($id)
        {
            //
            $mascota=Mascota::findOrFail($id);
            $razas = Raza::all();
            $propietarios = Propietario::all();
            return view('mascota.edit', compact('mascota', 'razas', 'propietarios'));
        }
```

my table:

```
 {
        Schema::create('mascotas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();


            $table->foreignId('id_raza')
                    ->nullable()
                    ->constrained('razas')
                    ->nullOnDelete()
                    ->cascadeOnUpdate();
            $table->timestamps();  
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `mascotas` has a `id_raza`, this value is needed to be able to set the `selected` option.

```
@foreach ($razas as $raza)
    @if (!empty($moscatas->id_raza) && $moscatas->id_raza == $raza->id)
        <option value="{{$raza->id}}" selected>{{ $raza->Nombre}}</option>
    @else
        <option value="{{$raza->id}}">{{ $raza->Nombre}}</option>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this,

```
<option value="{{ $raza->id }}" {{ 
$raza->id == $moscatas->id_raza ? 
'selected' : '' }}>
{{ $raza->Nombre}
</option>
```